# Restructure nested Object

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a problem. I have an object with this structure like this example.

```json
{
    "Name": "Peter",
    "Username": "dummy",
    "Age": 18,
    "moreData": {
        "tags": [1,2,3],
        "hasCar": true,
        "preferences": {
            "colors": ["green", "blue"]
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to convert it to an array like the following. I am desperate and can not get any further. I have issues as soon I get some nested objects. Does someone have an idea how I can achieve this? Kind Regards

```json
[
    {
        "key": "Name",
        "val": "Peter"
    },
    {
        "key": "Username",
        "val": "dummy"
    },
    {
        "key": "Age",
        "val": "18"
    },
    {
        "key": "tags",
        "val": [1,2,3]
    },
    {
        "key": "hasCar",
        "val": true
    },
    {
        "key": "colors",
        "val": ["green", "blue"]
    }
]
```

Comment: May you share with us the code that gives you issues? It’s always better to share a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to first iterate through all the key value pairs of your object and change the specific type of data into name value pairs except the nested objects. If the value in the object at a certain key is an object then the same procedure has to be done for it. And since there can be `N` number of levels for this nested data thus we need a recursive function for it. Whenever we have to do a same set of processing for nested data then it always means it can be done using recursion. It can be done via for loops too but a recursive function is much clear and lesser to write.

```
function getData(data) {
 let results = [];
 Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
   // If the type of the data item is object and is not an array, go into recursion
   if(typeof data[key] == 'object' && !Array.isArray(data[key])) {
      results = results.concat(getData(data[key]));
   } else {
      results.push({ key, val: data[key] });
   }
 });
 return results;
}

const data = {
  "Name": "Peter",
  "Username": "dummy",
  "Age": 18,
  "moreData": {
    "tags": [1,2,3],
    "hasCar": true,
    "preferences": {
        "colors": ["green", "blue"]
    }
  }
};

const results = getData(data);
console.log(results);
// [{"key":"Name","val":"Peter"},{"key":"Username","val":"dummy"},{"key":"Age","val":18},{"key":"tags","val":[1,2,3]},{"key":"hasCar","val":true},{"key":"colors","val":["green","blue"]}]
```