# Convert array of objects to CSV using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to convert a huge array into CSV file and map everything a

- First name
- Last name
- Contact info (This will be empty for now, we'll work on it next)
- Company score
- Past companies (separated by commas)
- Experience in months
- Skill score
- Skills (separated by commas)
- Last hired on
- Educational level (one of: Bachelor, Master, PhD)
- Degree (full name of the degree)
- Current location
- Source website (Only LinkedIn for now)
- Scraped on
- LinkedIn profile ID
- LinkedIn profile URL
- Exclusion reason (if excluded)

The sample object looks like this (i'm having a json file with 2000 objects like this)

```js
  {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "602436006778e70015217946"
      },
      "experiences": [],
      "folder": [
        {
          "companyName": "ProntoTV",
          "companyProfile": "https://www.linkedin.com/company/translated/",
          "companyWebsite": "",
          "profileId": "johndoe",
          "profileType": "LinkedIn",
          "scrapedOn": {
            "$date": "2021-02-10T19:37:33.654Z"
          },
          "firstName": "John",
          "lastName": "Doe",
          "from": {
            "$date": "2021-02-10T19:37:33.654Z"
          },
          "industry": "Translation & Localization",
          "url": "https://linkedin.com/in/xxxxxxxxx",
          "educations": [
            {
              "degree": "Laurea triennale",
              "field": "Ingegneria informatica",
              "from": null,
              "to": null,
              "singleDate": null,
              "schoolName": "Università degli Studi di Roma Tre",
              "order": 0
            }
          ],
          "positions": [
            {
              "companyName": "BYTEWISE",
              "from": {
                "$date": "2016-01-01T00:00:00Z"
              },
              "to": {
                "$date": "2016-07-01T00:00:00Z"
              },
              "singleDate": null,
              "order": 0,
              "title": "Junior Software Developer",
              "description": "Software Developer tirocinante.\nUtilizzo di varie tecnologie e linguaggi di programmazione, tra cui:\nJavascript\nC\nRaspberry PI\nFirewall Netfilter (Linux)\nProxy Squid\nDomain Controller ed Active Directory"
            },
            {
              "companyName": "Translated",
              "from": {
                "$date": "2020-05-01T00:00:00Z"
              },
              "to": null,
              "singleDate": null,
              "order": 1,
              "title": "Full-Stack Software Engineer"
            },
            {
              "companyName": "BYTEWISE",
              "from": {
                "$date": "2016-08-01T00:00:00Z"
              },
              "to": {
                "$date": "2020-05-01T00:00:00Z"
              },
              "singleDate": null,
              "order": 2,
              "title": "Full-Stack Software Engineer",
              "description": "Full-Stack Javascript Developer presso la società Bytewise Srl. \nSpecializzazione nell'utilizzo di ReactJS e NodeJS.\nGestione e programmazione di architetture Client / Server microservice based.\nManipolazione dei dati su motori di big data (ElasticSearch)\nUtilizzo di altre tecnologie per varie necessità, come Kotlin (o Java) per lo sviluppo di App Android, Php e C#, React Native e Ionic 2, Jquery ed Angular."
            }
          ],
          "skills": [
            {
              "order": 0,
              "value": "Typescript"
            },
            {
              "order": 1,
              "value": "PHP"
            },
            {
              "order": 2,
              "value": "React.js"
            },
            {
              "order": 3,
              "value": "C"
            },
            {
              "order": 4,
              "value": "C#"
            },
            {
              "order": 5,
              "value": "kotlin"
            },
            {
              "order": 6,
              "value": "Node.js"
            },
            {
              "order": 7,
              "value": "Big data"
            },
            {
              "order": 8,
              "value": "Git"
            },
            {
              "order": 9,
              "value": "java"
            },
            {
              "order": 10,
              "value": "React Native"
            },
            {
              "order": 11,
              "value": "Elasticsearch"
            },
            {
              "order": 12,
              "value": "Servizi Web RESTful"
            },
            {
              "order": 13,
              "value": "AngularJS"
            },
            {
              "order": 14,
              "value": "JavaScript"
            },
            {
              "order": 15,
              "value": "Ionic"
            },
            {
              "order": 16,
              "value": "Symfony"
            }
          ],
          "certificates": [
            {
              "order": 0,
              "name": "The Complete Node.js Developer Course",
              "url": "http://ude.my/UC-e06daa38-24a6-4462-8223-474d129325da",
              "authority": "Udemy",
              "from": {
                "$date": "2020-01-01T00:00:00Z"
              },
              "to": null,
              "singleDate": {
                "$date": "2020-01-01T00:00:00Z"
              }
            },
            {
              "order": 1,
              "name": "React Testing with Jest and Enzyme",
              "url": "http://ude.my/UC-bcaaf7bb-b9a7-4b3a-ba00-9daac1eb0b72",
              "authority": "Udemy",
              "from": {
                "$date": "2020-02-01T00:00:00Z"
              },
              "to": null,
              "singleDate": {
                "$date": "2020-02-01T00:00:00Z"
              }
            },
            {
              "order": 2,
              "name": "The Complete React Native And Hooks Course [2020 Edition]",
              "url": "http://ude.my/UC-CIS7W6I7",
              "authority": "Udemy",
              "from": {
                "$date": "2020-02-01T00:00:00Z"
              },
              "to": null,
              "singleDate": {
                "$date": "2020-02-01T00:00:00Z"
              }
            },
            {
              "order": 3,
              "name": "Modern React with Redux 2020",
              "url": "http://ude.my/UC-07a4831b-ea00-46e4-8e7c-886ffb887e69",
              "authority": "Udemy",
              "from": {
                "$date": "2020-02-01T00:00:00Z"
              },
              "to": null,
              "singleDate": {
                "$date": "2020-02-01T00:00:00Z"
              }
            }
          ],
          "volunteerExps": [],
          "accomplishments": {
            "courses": [],
            "honors": [],
            "languages": [
              {
                "name": "Inglese",
                "proficiency": "PROFESSIONAL_WORKING"
              },
              {
                "name": "Italiano",
                "proficiency": "NATIVE_OR_BILINGUAL"
              }
            ],
            "organizations": [],
            "projects": [
              {
                "order": 0,
                "description": "Il progetto consiste nella realizzazione di un sistema Sistema Firewall - Proxy per la Navigazione Internet Integrato con Tecnologia NFC.\n\nIl problema che punta a risolvere è quello della sicurezza della navigazione web in ambito lavorativo.\nNelle attuali architetture aziendali, tutti i computer sono generalmente messi in dominio e la navigazione è controllata da un Proxy, che traccia tutti i dati abbinandoli al profilo da cui provengono.\nLasciare il proprio computer sbloccato quando si è lontani dalla postazione permetterebbe ad altre persone malintenzionate di poter navigare liberamente sul web, facendo ricadere eventuali colpe delle proprie azioni verso il proprietario della postazione.\n\nIl sistema proposto in questo progetto prevede un Raspberry PI con annesso un lettore NFC collocato all'interno di un piccolo case accanto ad ogni postazione. La navigazione internet parte inizialmente bloccata dal Firewall di rete. \nL'utente ha a disposizione un Tag NFC con il quale può sbloccare, avvicinandolo al lettore, la navigazione web per un periodo limitato di tempo. Passando successivamente il Tag, viene nuovamente disabilitata. In questo modo all'utente che si allontana dalla propria postazione, per essere sicuro che nessuno navighi su internet dal suo pc, basta un semplice gesto con il quale disabilitare tale funzione.\n\nL'infrastruttura prevede le seguenti tecnologie:\n- Due demoni scritti in C in ambiente Linux, uno lato client che gira nel Raspeberry PI, uno lato server in ascolto sul Firewall.\n- Raspberry PI, lettore NFC, e librerie per la gestione dei segnali.\n- Utilizzo di Socket per lo scambio di dati.\n- Proxy Squid, per il tracciamento della navigazione\n- Firewall Netfilter, per bloccare o sbloccare la navigazione, andando ad aggiungere o rimuovere una specifica regola dalle sue tabelle.",
                "from": {
                  "$date": "2016-05-01T00:00:00Z"
                },
                "to": {
                  "$date": "2016-08-01T00:00:00Z"
                },
                "singleDate": {
                  "$date": "2016-08-01T00:00:00Z"
                }
              }
            ],
            "publications": []
          }
        }
      ],
      "updatedOn": {
        "$date": "2021-02-10T19:37:36.747Z"
      },
      "exclusionReason": [
        "Company name"
      ],
      "experienceInMonths": 60,
      "isBachelor": false,
      "isMaster": false,
      "isPhd": false,
      "companyPoints": 1,
      "stackScore": 4,
      "hiringDate" 2020-1-1
    },
```

But I am not able to access the object properties such as First name, Last name, Past companies, current Location etc. (can't access the whole "Folder" array)

Here is my code:

```
function CSV(fileToRank) {
  // Use first element to choose the keys and the order
  var keys = Object.keys(fileToRank[0]);

  // Build header
  var result = keys.join("\t") + "\n";

  // Add the rows
  fileToRank.forEach(function(obj){
      result += keys.map(k => obj[k]).join("\t") + "\n";
  });
  console.log(result)
  return result;
}
```

But the result that I'm getting is:

```
[object Object]         [object Object] [object Object]         19      true    false   false   0       0       2020-10-1
[object Object]         [object Object] [object Object]         19      false   false   false   0       1       2019-11-1
[object Object]         [object Object] [object Object]         18      false   false   false   0       0       2020-7-1
[object Object]         [object Object] [object Object]         18      false   true    false   0       0       2019-8-1
```

How can I access the array "Folder" and objects in this array? I need to map it correctly but not sure how to achieve it. Been reccomended to use "Blob" but the Blob is I think unneccesary

Comment: The problem is with the nested data structure. You have nested objects in the current object value and you are not handling it in the CSV() function which will only work for premitive values which are singleton like numbers, string, boolean, etc

Comment: Check my answer on this question for iterating the nested json data structure and flattened itt. You can refer and modify it as per your requirement. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66398281/restructure-nested-object

Comment: What's the proper way to solve it?

Comment: For example if type of obj[k] is object then that means you need to change it to one value like obj[k].join(',') if its an array or else something like  JSON.stringify(obj[k])

Comment: What you are doing is correct way just check and decide how the data for "folder" should be shown in the csv file and according to that change the data handling in CSV() function

Comment: One question because I'm not sure - how would you handle blanks? Like, Company score, Stack score? Because I'm having some values that equals to blanks and getting error TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: If obj[k] is blank then I can put empty sting `''` or maybe I can put a space in there `' '`

Comment: Thanks man, really appreciate your help - by simply adding && data[key] !== null || undefined to if statement got this working

Comment: Oh you mean that??? Just use `&& !data[key]` it will be true for all the 3 cases null, undefined and empty string `''`